# Too many pythons on my Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion

I updated to Mountain Lion not long ago, and having used python previously, I now have 8 (yes, 8) versions of python installed on my computer.

```
$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  204 Jun 20 16:23 2.3
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Aug 22 13:32 2.5
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Aug 22 13:32 2.6
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Aug 22 13:32 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jul 29 17:41 Current -> 2.7
```

I would love to erase all of them and clean everything up, and I prefer to set all paths to the **system** python that comes with Mountain Lion. My goal is simplicity and cleanliness.  I have been trying to do this for literally almost six months, off and on... there are a multitude of "solutions" and scripts available on the web for this problem, and none of them fully work or are even understandable.  Can anyone tell me how to get these unwanted Python versions off of my Mac, or at least how to set my Mac so that everything goes nicely into the Mac system version of python.  I don't have too many old Python files I particularly need to use, but I've noticed that I have trouble installing Python stuff and running .py scripts because the paths are all mixed up or something to that effect.

Also, I get this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

...kind of scary-looking.

Thanks for your help. I am familiar with UNIX shell scripting and have a mid-level understanding of system admin stuff... but not advanced. I am a programmer in R so I know how to program and all of that. Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: WHere is your path set ?  in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile ?

Comment: WHat trouble in installing ython stuff - all the ones you have are possible Apple installs added when you upgraded the OS

Comment: Keep in mind that you probably shouldn't remove versions of Python that come installed with OS X (as it's probably included because it's used by OS X).

Comment: Yeah, that is my main problem: I don't want to remove the version of Python that came with OS X.  I just have other ones on there that I installed when I was taking a python class in school.  Mark, I do not know if they are Apple installs or not.  That is also an issue.  And, I don't know how to find out where my path is set, nor do I know how to find out (cheeks turning red with shame).

Comment: @user1864671: Anything in `/System` is an Apple install.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have 5, yes 5, versions, not 8, not 8. And 4 of those 5 are part of the OS and should never be removed. So you only have 1 excess, not 7.

```
ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  204 Jun 20 16:23 2.3
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Aug 22 13:32 2.5
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Aug 22 13:32 2.6
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Aug 22 13:32 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jul 29 17:41 Current -> 2.7
```

That's 4. A symlink `Current -> 2.7` is not another version, it's the same version again. These 4 all come with your system, and may be used by tools that are part of the system. You should not ever get rid of them, or anything else inside the `/System` directory (or the `/usr/bin` shortcuts that launch them).

Meanwhile, you have these in your path:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin
```

That's just three copies of the same version, most likely the official Python 2.7 from python.org. My guess is that you ran the old-style installer once, and then ran the newer installer once.

But it doesn't matter how they got there (unless it was through `Homebrew`, in which case just `brew unlink python` and you're done). You get rid of it by following the uninstall instructions at python.org, and then you will have only the minimal 4 again.

After a quick check, I can't find the page that used to have the simple uninstall instructions at python.org, but basically, it's this:

```
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

You can then do an `ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep Python.framework` and `rm` everything that turns up. (You can automate that, but it's probably better to see exactly what you're deleting.)

You may also want to find what's adding the extra stuff to your PATH. Likely places to look are `~/.bash_profile` (where the python.org installers do it), similar files like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` (where others may have told you to put it), and possibly `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d` (where you may have put it to make it work with GUI apps).

Comment: I have a question... I want to remove the extra stuff from my path.  I'm not sure what should actually stay in my PATH, though, and how to get the stuff I don't need there, out.  Also, how does one look in ~/.bash_profile and those other places?

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` is just a text file. The only trick is that it starts with a `.`, which means you won't see it in Finder, or in a GUI open dialog, unless you tell them to show hidden files. But from the Terminal, you can just `less ~/.bash_profile` to see it, or `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` to pop it open in TextEdit, etc. If you see a line like `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}`, that's the problem. It sounds like you should have 3 such lines somewhere.

Comment: One last thing: If you don't know much about this kind of stuff, you should either back up the hidden files before changing them, or comment out lines (just add a `#` before the first character) instead of deleting them, so you can get back later if you broke anything.