# How solve import error in Python when trying to import Numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

This is the error I get when trying to import numpy on opening python (2.7.8):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

This is the path of my python binary `/usr/local/bin/python`

This is the path of pip `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Also, when I put in `pip freeze` I found the numpy package `numpy==1.8.0rc1`

I have looked at other relevant questions, but I'm not able to diagnose the cause. I'm guessing it might be some problem in PATHS. Where do I start?

Comment: Do you have multiple Python installations on your machine? It happens that `pip` will sometimes simply install to the wrong Python version, in which case the solution is to explicitly specify which Python version you want by doing e.g. `pip-2.7` or `pip2.7`.

Comment: How do you 'open' Python, e.g. `ipython qtconsole` from the terminal.  You can confirm which version of python by typing `which python` from the terminal.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan should I be explicitly downloading pip2.7 for this case, because I'm sure I have Python 2.7.8, or should I be scraping for unnecessary Python installations.

Comment: @AkashSubramanian You can check what `python` is an alias for, and see if it corresponds to only the version you have.

Comment: @Alexander I type in `python` into the terminal. On typing `which python` I just get `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

As Akshat pointed out in the comments above, I had multiple versions of Python installed. This could have been the effect of using homebrew and/or macports in the past. I followed the steps detailed in [Too many pythons on my Mac OS X Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654756/too-many-pythons-on-my-mac-os-x-mountain-lion) 
and did a fresh install of Python 2.7.12 I was then able to reinstall pip and the packages subsequently.